# How do I do go error handling idiomatic way

Tags: go

I have a goroutine with logic:

```
result1, err := getResult1()
result2, err := getResult2(result)
result3, err := getResult3(result2)
```

If I have an error in getResult1(), I would not like to continue this goroutine at all, but no panic, because it destroy the main too. I've implemented it in an awful way, but what would be the idiomatic solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idiomátic way is *do something*

```golang
r, err := get()
if err != nil {
    // do something with err
    // do not continue
}
…
```

You can return the error to the caller, and the caller decide what to do.

You don’t need to panic. You can just log.

Or use the error in some loop to retry

Comment: "// do not continue", in that case, how to tell to the goroutine exactly to not continue with "result2, err := getResult2(result)" ?

Comment: using `return` for instance

Answer (score 3):

In golang it's better to handle errors as soon as they occur

```
result1, err := getResult1()
if err != nil {
    // log your error and return
    return err
}
result2, err := getResult2(result)
result3, err := getResult3(result2)
```

If you need to handle panics and regain control over panicking goroutine, then recover() is your way to go:

```
 defer func() {
    if r := recover(); r != nil {
        fmt.Println("Recovering my panicing goroutine", r)
    }
}()
```